# Preprocessing C99 digraphs away

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c99, digraphs

Is there a way to "preprocess" C99-style digraphs to obtain a C file (or a `.i` preprocessed source) such that the resulting file does not contain any digraphs?

For instance, given the following source code:

```
%:define N 5

int main() <%
  int a<:N:> = <%2,1,0%>;
  char *s = "a<:b";
  return a<:4:>;
%>
```

Using GCC's preprocessor option (`-E`, plus `-dD` for good measure) is sufficient to get rid of the `%:` digraph (which gets evaluated and re-printed as `#define` in this example), but not the others.

Clang behaves in the same way, so it doesn't help much.

As far as I understand, simple regular expression substitutions would not work, since they would end up replacing occurrences inside strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no standard tool which does this transformation. In particular, the preprocessor does *not* substitute digraphs, because (unlike trigraphs) digraphs are just ordinary tokens which happen to mean the same thing as other ordinary tokens.

It would be relatively straightforward to write such a processor using `flex`, starting with an existing flex definition for C.